# Unity 2d with the Android platform crashes with the urp package

Tags: unity, unity-urp

I’m new to developing lights in Unity, I looked at the tutorials and decided to use the URP package. When installing the package, the project crashed at first, but then I restarted and the textures became strange (bright colors). This project initially had an Android platform without a URP package.
[image]

I decided to try to create a new 2d test project with a windows platform. The URP package works fine until I install the platform on Android. Unity immediately crashes and it is impossible to enter the project
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you may have a corrupted installation of Unity, your Android SDK, or the package in your package cache. I'd recommend uninstalling all Unity/Android related software and reinstalling them from scratch to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @DMGregory I reinstalled Unity from scratch, it didn't help.

Comment: Did you do the same with your Android development environment, SDK, etc?

Comment: @DMGregory I tried it, uninstalled it completely on the computer, then I also tried installing Android manually through the official website, it didn’t help. Maybe the problem is in the URP package? in fact, if I don’t use it, the Android platform works fine, I can even build an apk file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the outdated driver on the video adapter, I updated it to the new version and everything worked.
Maybe it will help someone,

https://discussions.unity.com/t/amddxgsafreecompiledshader-unity-2022-3-14f1-2d-with-the-android-platform-crashes-with-the-urp-package/315276/3